# Pivot dataframe with multiple categorical variables into sparse matrix

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table, sparse-matrix, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to pivot a dataframe with categorical features directly into a sparse matrix. My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296383/how-to-cope-around-memory-overflow-with-pivot-table), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661604/efficiently-create-sparse-pivot-tables-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1), but my dataframe contains multiple categorical variables, so those approaches don't work.

This code currently works, but `df.pivot()` works with a dense matrix and with my real dataset, I run out of RAM. Can you suggest a way to work with sparse matrices from the start?

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Example dataframe
data = {
  'id':[13,13,14,14,14,15],
  'name':['alex', 'mary', 'alex', 'barry', 'john', 'john'],
  'categ': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'ant', 'fox', 'seal'],
  'size': ['big', 'small', 'big', 'tiny', 'medium', 'big']

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pivoting -- problematic step creating a huge dense matrix
pivot = df.pivot(index='id', columns='name', values=['categ','size']).fillna('-')
cols = pivot.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')
pivot.columns = cols

# One hot encoding into a sparse matrix
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=True)
pivot_enc = encoder.fit_transform(pivot)
pivot = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    pivot_enc, columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out())

print(pivot.dtypes)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in using a groupby(), which can work with `Sparse` types directly, but only if categorical variables are first encoded using `.cat.codes`.

Here is the answer which uses sparse matrices throughout:

```py
for col in ['categ', 'size']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category').cat.codes

# Group by into sparse columns
piv = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])[['categ', 'size']].first().astype('Sparse')

# Unstack keeps sparse format
piv = piv.unstack(fill_value=0)

piv.columns = piv.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')

# Encoding works as previously
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=True)
piv_enc = encoder.fit_transform(piv)
piv_fin = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    piv_enc, columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out())
```

The way to keep the original category labels can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005968/onehotencoder-keep-feature-names-after-encoding-categorical-variables).