# OneHotEncoder -- keep feature names after encoding categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

#### Question

After encoding categorical columns as numbers and pivoting LONG to WIDE into a sparse matrix, I am trying to retrieve the category labels for column names. I need this information to interpret the model in a latter step.

#### Solution

Below is my solution, which is really convoluted, please let me know if you have a better way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Example dataframe
data = {
  'id':[13,13,14,14,14,15],
  'name':['alex', 'mary', 'alex', 'barry', 'john', 'john'],
  'categ': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'ant', 'fox', 'seal'],
  'size': ['big', 'small', 'big', 'tiny', 'medium', 'big']

}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create dictionaries from original dataframe to save categories
# Part of the convoluted solution
dcts = []
df_cols = ['categ', 'size']

for col in df_cols:
    cats = df[col].astype('category')
    dct = dict(enumerate(cats.cat.categories))
    dcts.append(dct)

# Change into category codes, otherwise sparse matrix cannot be built
for col in ['categ', 'size']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category').cat.codes

# Group by into sparse columns
piv = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])[['categ', 'size']].first().astype('Sparse[int]')

# Unstack keeps sparse format
piv = piv.unstack(fill_value=0)

piv.columns = piv.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')

# Encoding gives poor column names
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=True)
piv_enc = encoder.fit_transform(piv)
piv_fin = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    piv_enc, columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out())
```

The column names look like this: `'categ_alex_-', 'categ_alex_2.0', 'categ_barry_-', 'categ_barry_0.0'`, while we need the original category labels, i.e. `'categ_alex_-', 'categ_alex_dog', 'categ_barry_-', 'categ_barry_ant'`.

#### Convoluted part I need advice on

```py
# Fixing column names
piv_cols = list(piv_fin.columns)
for (dct, df_col) in zip(dcts, df_cols):
    print(df_col, dct)
    for i, piv_col in enumerate(piv_cols):
        if df_col in piv_col:
            if piv_col[-1:] != '-':
                piv_cols[i] = piv_col[:-2] + '_' + dct[int(piv_col[-1:])]

piv_fin.columns = piv_cols
```

I'm sure there's a better way, perhaps OneHotEncoder can use category labels directly? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make things a bit easier by using a dictionary instead of a list to save categories:

```py
# Create dictionaries from original dataframe to save categories
dcts = {}  # instead of []
df_cols = ["categ", "size"]

for col in df_cols:
    cats = df[col].astype("category")
    dct = dict(enumerate(cats.cat.categories))
    dcts[col] = dct  # instead of dcts.append(dct)
```

Then, using [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) from Python standard library:

```py
# Fixing column names
piv_cols = [
    col.replace(col[-1], dcts[col.split("_")[0]][int(col[-1])])
    if str.isnumeric(col[-1])
    else col
    for col in piv_fin.columns
]
```

So that:

```py
print(piv_cols)
# Output

['categ_alex_-',
 'categ_alex_dog',
 'categ_barry_-',
 'categ_barry_ant',
 'categ_john_-',
 'categ_john_fox',
 'categ_john_seal',
 'categ_mary_-',
 'categ_mary_cat',
 'size_alex_-',
 'size_alex_big',
 'size_barry_-',
 'size_barry_tiny',
 'size_john_-',
 'size_john_big',
 'size_john_medium',
 'size_mary_-',
 'size_mary_small']
```

Comment: One caveat -- if your column names contain numbers (in my toy example they didn't, but the real dataset does), string.replace() replaces valid numbers by a value from dictionary. Therefore, I ended up using `col[:-1] + dcts[col.split('_')[0]][int(col[-1])]` instead of `col.replace()`.